# how to get json file into javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i asked a question here but the guy who answered me left me distracted and didn't reply me in what to do exactly.
i'm trying to implement a local massive data json file into my javascript file i tried this but doesn't work kept return 0.

```
    function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
{
  let gridcode = 0;
$.getJSON('example.json',function( data ) {

  var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)
  if (result) { gridcode = result.GRIDCODE;}
});
return gridcode;
};
```

the concept of this function is when i enter the lat and long it should return the grid code associated to them. 
this is what i understand form that gut anser but doesn't work

```
   function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)

      if (result) {
        resolve(result.GRIDCODE)
      } else {
        reject()
      }
  });
})};

$("#Btn" ).click(function()
{
var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
long = document.getElementById("long").value;
lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
.then(gridcode => {
var result = gridcode;
})
  $("#result").html(result);

});
```

this is how my data look like

```
[{"GRIDCODE":1765,"lat":35.916,"long":-5.401},{"GRIDCODE":1807,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.467},{"GRIDCODE":1798,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.459},{"GRIDCODE":1546,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.409},{"GRIDCODE":1667,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.401},{"GRIDCODE":1729,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.384},{"GRIDCODE":1756,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.484},{"GRIDCODE":1773,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.476},{"GRIDCODE":1828,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.467},{"GRIDCODE":1842,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.459},{"GRIDCODE":1779,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.451},{"GRIDCODE":1728,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.442},{"GRIDCODE":1773,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.434},{"GRIDCODE":1609,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.426}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `result` variable outside `.then()`. You must wait until async operation completes.

```
$("#Btn" ).click(function()
{
 var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
 long = document.getElementById("long").value;
 lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
  .then(gridcode => {
    $("#result").innerHTML(gridcode ); // Update value here
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to thank that guy, he put you in to right direction using promises, Try learning about promises in javascript. I modified your code a bit to add error handling.

```
function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)
      if (result) {
        resolve(result.GRIDCODE)
      } else {
        reject(new Error('No records found'))
      }
  });
})};

$("#Btn").click(function(){
  var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
  long = document.getElementById("long").value;
  lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
  .then(gridcode => {
    var result = gridcode;
    $("#result").html(result);
  }).catch(err => {
    //handle error here
    console.log(err)
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot well i did try it but didn't work i get error in the console about libraries.js:1714 GET http://localhost/asset-manifest.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: make sure you change example.json in $.getJson to your proper endpoint

Comment: i fixed it thanks  prb now i face the `[Violation] 'load' handler took 303ms` becose of the big data

Comment: Instead of doing search on clientside, write api to do it on server and only return required data.

Comment: I have no experience with API that fetch Data from a server but thank you i do really appreciate it so much.